# \!Tensorflow flow_from_dataframe() gives "invalid filenames" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, jupyter-lab

I'm practicing object recognition with TS and Keras using Jupyter-lab (Windows OS) on the well-known Cats-Dogs Dataset. I've followed up some tutorials on the web, but i've encountered an exception about the format of the images' names:

```
C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py:989: UserWarning: Found 34876 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="filename". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  warnings.warn('Found {} invalid image filename(s) in x_col="{}". '
```

The Path to the training folder is: *C:\Users***\Documents\PetImages\Cats_Dogs*, the piece of code of interest is:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df,
                                                 "C:/Users/Edo/Documents/PetImages/Cats_Dogs",x_col='filename',y_col='category',
                                                 target_size=Image_Size,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 batch_size=batch_size)
validation_datagen = IDG(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validate_df, 
    "C:/Users/***/Documents/PetImages/Cats_Dogs", 
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=Image_Size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Where IDG stays for the ImageDataGenerator lib.

x_col is the parameter throwing the error.

The training folder is structured as such:

[image: starting files]

With all the jpg files renamed in a **sequential order of one-digit integers**.

What am i missing? I've searched all the way around but can't actually manage to find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

problem must be that train_df['filename'] is incorrect. Use the code below to print outthe first value

`````
import os
import cv2
file_id=train_df['filename'].iloc[0]
print (file_id)
sdir=r'C:/Users/Edo/Documents/PetImages/Cats_Dogs'
file_path=os.path.join(sdir, file_id) # should be full path to the image file
print(file_path)
try:
    image=cv2.imread(file_path)
    shape=image.shape
    print(shape)
except:
    print('Invalid image file')
````
Check if the file_id is correct. Check if the file_path is correct. If they are then
cv2 should be able to read in the image and print its shape.

````
`````